# Spring TaskExecutor with barrier

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-3

Is there a way in Spring (using TaskExecutor ) to execute several tasks in parallel , and  wait (barrier) till all of the tasks are finished ?

I found an example here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/ 
which uses an infinite loop .

Isn't there any better approach provided by Spring for this?

Comment: Do you only want to wait for some (fixed number of) tasks to finish? I'm not sure if you need Spring for this. Check if using a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function `shutdown` of the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

In fact this function is called at the end of the execution of the tasks. Therefore if you put some code in it, you can for instance warn all the listeners that the job is done.

```
@Override
public function void shutdown() {
     logger.info("My tasks are done !") ;
     // TODO warn listeners
}
```